# How to access iMessage library using Sequel Pro on macOS

Tags: messages, data, sqlite

I'd like to access my iMessages using Sequel Pro. I have been told that they are in a sqllite file.

Answer (score 1):

Messages uses an SQLite database structure, so you can't open this with Sequel Pro. You can open the Messages database at ~/Library/Messages/chat.db using [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org).